# How to downgrade tensorflow 2.0.1 to 0.9.0? in Mac OS

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
$ pip install tensorflow==0.9.0
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==0.9.0 (from versions: 2.0.1)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==0.9.0

I don't know the reason...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a virtual environment and then fresh install TF using `pip install "tensorflow==0.9.0"`

Comment: Before the upgrade, the $ Jupyternotebook was run immediately. I wonder if there is no way to downgrade without using virtual environment  :( . Thx

Comment: Create virtual environment (venv), I tried to install "tensorflow==0.9.0" ..
// ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==0.9.0 (from versions: 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==0.9.0
// But, still have same problem :(

Comment: I am having the same issue. Frustrating this is so much harder on the newer macs.